Will the pressure on the high-pressure side of a moving object in air be mirrored by an equal but opposite pressure on the low-pressure side?
Say you have an atmosphere of room temperature, sea level, 0% humidity air.
Then, imagine you have a steel cube moving through the air with one of the six faces directly into the wind.
If it’s moving fast enough (above Mach 0.3 flow becomes compressible), the side facing the wind will be higher pressure.
I have no idea about the actual numbers, but say the cube is moving fast enough that the side facing the oncoming air is +1 PSI above ambient.
My question is, will the opposite side be -1 PSI below ambient?
So basically will the side that is facing opposite of the direction of movement be -1 PSI.

You could also say I’m asking if it will be an exact opposite pressure differential.
Also, this question is asking about static pressure, not dynamic.

You're asking whether a shape that is symmetrical about its midpoint can have an anti-symmetric pressure distribution.  Why would you expect that? In ideal flow (no viscous effects) the distribution would be symmetric. Including viscosity on a streamlined shape would only alter that a pattern a small amount. For a shape like the cube you have specified, there would be massive flow separation at the midpoint, with downstream pressures approximately equal to the freestream values. In no case would an antisymmetric distribution be expected.

@D.Halsey I see. So would the separation cause an asymmetrical pressure distribution? If so, would it increase or decrease pressure? Thanks.


will the side that is facing opposite of the direction of movement be -1 PSI.

No
The following plot shows the distribution of the pressure coefficient on a cube (figure 3 of this paper):

The segment from 0 to 1 represents the pressure coefficient on the forward face of the cube; 1 to 2 the upper surface; and 2 to 3 the rear surface.
As visible, the pressure coefficient on the front surface is positive i.e. the pressure is higher than the freestream. Instead, on the upper and rear surface the pressure is lower so there's a suction on these parts of the cube. Anyway the suction on the rear part is much smaller than the push on the front surface, some -0.3 instead of +0.7 respectively.
